Manipulate page with electron
Thank you in advance for your help.
I want to create a script for web scraping using different technologies. This is my main script, and the goal is to ensure that it cannot be changed.

//main//
const main = async (page) => {

    const url = 'https://app.proxiesapi.com/login/index.php';
    await page.goto(url);

    await page.waitForFunction(() => document.readyState === 'complete')

    const email = 'xxx@gmail.com';
    await page.evaluate(({ email }) => {
        document.querySelector('#myusername').value = email;
    }, { email });

    const inputFieldValue = await page.evaluate(() => {
        return document.querySelector('#myusername').value;
    });

    console.log({ inputFieldValue });
    return page;
};

export { main };


that is my script electron :
import { app, BrowserWindow, session } from 'electron';
import { main } from './script.js';

// create browser /page //
export async function createBrowser() {
    await app.whenReady();
    const browserWindow = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600, show: true });
    return browserWindow;
}
async function createTab(browser) {
    return browser;
}

// go to url//
async function goto(page, url) {
    await page.loadURL(url);
    return page;
}

// evaluate electron style//
const evaluate = async (page, func, args) => {
    const funcStr = `(${func})(${JSON.stringify(args)})`;
    return await page.webContents.executeJavaScript(funcStr);
}

// wait Load // 
const waitForFunction = async (page, func) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
            page.webContents.executeJavaScript(`(${func})()`).then((result) => {
                if (result) {
                    clearInterval(intervalId);
                    resolve(result);
                }
            }).catch(console.error);
        }, 100);
    });
}

async function clear(tab, browser) {
    await session.defaultSession.clearStorageData();
    tab.close();
    await browser.close();
}

// Call function //
(async () => {
    const browser = await createBrowser();
    let page = await createTab(browser);

    page.goto = goto.bind(null, page);
    page.waitForFunction = waitForFunction.bind(null, page);
    page.evaluate = evaluate.bind(null, page);

    page = await main(page);

    await clear(page, browser);
})();

It is functional, but I do not want to use things like eval() or executeJavaScript. Instead, I would like to directly inject my script into the page. Do you know how to do that with Electron?

You have to use preload.js script for it.
update your electron script
webPreferences: {
  preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'), // Path to preload script
  contextIsolation: true,
  enableRemoteModule: false
}

add wait load
const waitForFunction = async (page, func) => {
    return page.webContents.executeJavaScript(`window.electron.waitForFunction(${JSON.stringify(func)})`);
}

update your call function accordingly.
In your preload.js create contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld with adding the waitForFunction and the set value and get value.
Then you can avoid using eval()
